# Problems with Hibernate updates and foreign keys

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am working on a JEE development that implements Hibernate.  I have used Hibernate in the past but never had to set it up and configure it.  The developers who set up this application are now long gone and those left really don't know more than how to use it (mostly).

The biggest problem we are encountering is one module creates a new entry on a table.  In the same process a succeeding module wants to create an entry on a table that has a foreign key to the first table, specifically the key of the entry the first module just created.  That fails.  Hibernate says the first key doesn't exist.  However if I check after the test is over the database the entry is there.

I went into debug and stopped the process just before it attempts to create the second entry.  If I check the database at that point the first entry is definitely not on the database yet.  I wasn't surprised by that since Hibernate caches updates.  It only physically updates on it's own schedule.  But what I can't understand is why it is saying the first entry doesn't exist.  What is causing this?

I'm not sure what to give you to show our setup so I will provide some things and hopefully can get some feedback.

We are using Wildfly 10, Hibernate 5.1.0.Final and Postgresql 9.4.1208.jre7.

Here is the setup of datasource in WildFly standalone.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
        <datasources>
            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/CMA_DS" pool-name="java:jboss/datasources/CMA_DS" enabled="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                    cma
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                    localhost
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                    5432
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="User">
                    user
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="Password">
                    psw
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                <driver>postgres</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </xa-pool>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="postgres" module="org.postgresql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Persistence.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="CMA_DS">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/CMA_DS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.cma.config.FixedPostgreSQL94Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.default_cache_concurrency_strategy" value="nonstrict-read-write" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="15" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And this is the SQL for the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE zones
(
  id numeric NOT NULL, -- Generated id field
  description character varying(250), 
  lat_degree numeric, 
  lat_minute numeric, 
  lat_hemisphere character varying(1),
  long_degree numeric,
  long_minute numeric, 
  long_hemisphere character varying(1), 
  national_loc_id character varying(61), 
  global_loc_num character varying(13), 
  zone_name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  country_code character(3),
  party_organization_id character varying(15),
  owner_nation character(3),
  local_owner boolean,
  CONSTRAINT pk_zones PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT zones_global_loc_num_key UNIQUE (global_loc_num),
  CONSTRAINT "zones_national_loc-id_key" UNIQUE (national_loc_id, country_code),
  CONSTRAINT zones_zone_name_key UNIQUE (zone_name, owner_nation)
);

CREATE TABLE party_id_tracking
(
  id numeric NOT NULL, 
  zone_id numeric, 
  endpoint_id numeric, 
  notified_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_party_id_tracking PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT party_id_tracking_endpoint_fk FOREIGN KEY (endpoint_id)
      REFERENCES routing_endpoint (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT party_id_tracking_zone_fk FOREIGN KEY (zone_id)
      REFERENCES zones (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

The entity for the Zone table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zones")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Zone extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5828384364074883963L;
   @Column(name = "zone_name")
    private String zoneName;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "lat_degree")
    private Integer latDegree;
    @Column(name = "lat_minute")
    private Float latMinute;
    @Column(name = "lat_hemisphere")
    private String latHemisphere;
    @Column(name = "long_degree")
    private Integer longDegree;
    @Column(name = "long_minute")
    private Float longMinute;
    @Column(name = "long_hemisphere")
    private String longHemisphere;
    @Column(name = "national_loc_id")
    private String nationalLocID;
    @Column(name = "global_loc_num")
    private String globalLocNum;
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;
    @Column(name = "owner_nation")
    private String ownerNation;
    @Column(name = "party_organization_id")
    private String partyOrganizationId;
    @Column(name = "local_owner")
    private Boolean localOwner;
    public Zone() {
        super();
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Integer getLatDegree() {
        return this.latDegree;
    }
    public void setLatDegree(Integer latDegree) {
        this.latDegree = latDegree;
    }
    public String getLatHemisphere() {
        return this.latHemisphere;
    }
    public void setLatHemisphere(String latHemisphere) {
        this.latHemisphere = latHemisphere;
    }
    public Integer getLongDegree() {
        return this.longDegree;
    }
    public void setLongDegree(Integer longDegree) {
        this.longDegree = longDegree;
    }
    public String getLongHemisphere() {
        return this.longHemisphere;
    }
    public void setLongHemisphere(String longHemisphere) {
        this.longHemisphere = longHemisphere;
    }
    public String getNationalLocID() {
        return this.nationalLocID;
    }
    public void setNationalLocID(String nationalLocID) {
        this.nationalLocID = nationalLocID;
    }
    public String getGlobalLocNum() {
        return this.globalLocNum;
    }
    public void setGlobalLocNum(String globalLocNum) {
        this.globalLocNum = globalLocNum;
    }
    public Float getLatMinute() {
        return this.latMinute;
    }
   public void setLatMinute(Float latMinute) {
        this.latMinute = latMinute;
    }
    public Float getLongMinute() {
        return this.longMinute;
    }
   public void setLongMinute(Float longMinute) {
        this.longMinute = longMinute;
    }
   public String getZoneName() {
        return this.zoneName;
    }
    public void setZoneName(String zoneName) {
        this.zoneName = zoneName;
    }
    public String getCountryCode() {
        return this.countryCode;
    }
    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }
    public String getOwnerNation() {
        return this.ownerNation;
    }
    public void setOwnerNation(String ownerNation) {
        this.ownerNation = ownerNation;
    }
   public String getPartyOrganizationId() {
        return this.partyOrganizationId;
    }
    public void setPartyOrganizationId(String partyOrganizationId) {
        this.partyOrganizationId = partyOrganizationId;
    }
    public Boolean getLocalOwner() {
        return this.localOwner;
    }
    public void setLocalOwner(Boolean localOwner) {
        this.localOwner = localOwner;
    }
}
```

And the tracking table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "party_id_tracking")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class PartyIdTracking extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "notified_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date notifiedDate;
    @Column(name = "endpoint_id")
    private Long endpointId;
    @Column(name = "zone_id")
    private Long zoneId;
    public Date getNotifiedDate() {
        return this.notifiedDate;
    }
    public void setNotifiedDate(Date notifiedDate) {
        this.notifiedDate = notifiedDate;
    }
    public Long getEndpointId() {
        return this.endpointId;
    }
    public void setEndpointId(Long endpointId) {
        this.endpointId = endpointId;
    }
    public Long getZoneId() {
        return this.zoneId;
    }
    public void setZoneId(Long zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }
}
```

We are having similar problems with several transactions in the application.  An entry gets created in the table and we immediately need to insert other entries that depend on that first entry.  We keep getting failures because it thinks the first entry doesn't exist.

We have tried using flush.  But that didn't help.

What do we do?

Comment: Where is the mapping from in the entities? You have a foreign key from party_id_tracking to zone, that need to map properly. I think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified your entity table like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zones")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Zone extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5828384364074883963L;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "zones", cascade =   CascadeType.ALL)
    private PartyIdTracking partyIdTracking;

    @Column(name = "zone_name")
    private String zoneName;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "lat_degree")
    private Integer latDegree;
    @Column(name = "lat_minute")
    private Float latMinute;
    @Column(name = "lat_hemisphere")
    private String latHemisphere;
    @Column(name = "long_degree")
    private Integer longDegree;
    @Column(name = "long_minute")
    private Float longMinute;
    @Column(name = "long_hemisphere")
    private String longHemisphere;
    @Column(name = "national_loc_id")
    private String nationalLocID;
    @Column(name = "global_loc_num")
    private String globalLocNum;
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;
    @Column(name = "owner_nation")
    private String ownerNation;
    @Column(name = "party_organization_id")
    private String partyOrganizationId;
    @Column(name = "local_owner")
    private Boolean localOwner;
    public Zone() {
        super();
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Integer getLatDegree() {
        return this.latDegree;
    }
    public void setLatDegree(Integer latDegree) {
        this.latDegree = latDegree;
    }
    public String getLatHemisphere() {
        return this.latHemisphere;
    }
    public void setLatHemisphere(String latHemisphere) {
        this.latHemisphere = latHemisphere;
    }
    public Integer getLongDegree() {
        return this.longDegree;
    }
    public void setLongDegree(Integer longDegree) {
        this.longDegree = longDegree;
    }
    public String getLongHemisphere() {
        return this.longHemisphere;
    }
    public void setLongHemisphere(String longHemisphere) {
        this.longHemisphere = longHemisphere;
    }
    public String getNationalLocID() {
        return this.nationalLocID;
    }
    public void setNationalLocID(String nationalLocID) {
        this.nationalLocID = nationalLocID;
    }
    public String getGlobalLocNum() {
        return this.globalLocNum;
    }
    public void setGlobalLocNum(String globalLocNum) {
        this.globalLocNum = globalLocNum;
    }
    public Float getLatMinute() {
        return this.latMinute;
    }
   public void setLatMinute(Float latMinute) {
        this.latMinute = latMinute;
    }
    public Float getLongMinute() {
        return this.longMinute;
    }
   public void setLongMinute(Float longMinute) {
        this.longMinute = longMinute;
    }
   public String getZoneName() {
        return this.zoneName;
    }
    public void setZoneName(String zoneName) {
        this.zoneName = zoneName;
    }
    public String getCountryCode() {
        return this.countryCode;
    }
    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }
    public String getOwnerNation() {
        return this.ownerNation;
    }
    public void setOwnerNation(String ownerNation) {
        this.ownerNation = ownerNation;
    }
   public String getPartyOrganizationId() {
        return this.partyOrganizationId;
    }
    public void setPartyOrganizationId(String partyOrganizationId) {
        this.partyOrganizationId = partyOrganizationId;
    }
    public Boolean getLocalOwner() {
        return this.localOwner;
    }
    public void setLocalOwner(Boolean localOwner) {
        this.localOwner = localOwner;
    }
    public Boolean getPartyIdTracking () {
        return this.partyIdTracking ;
    }
    public void setPartyIdTracking (PartyIdTracking partyIdTracking ) {
        this.partyIdTracking = partyIdTracking ;
    }
}
```

And the tracking table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "party_id_tracking")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class PartyIdTracking extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Zone zone;

    @Column(name = "notified_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date notifiedDate;
    @Column(name = "endpoint_id")
    private Long endpointId;
    @Column(name = "zone_id")
    private Long zoneId;
    public Date getNotifiedDate() {
        return this.notifiedDate;
    }
    public void setNotifiedDate(Date notifiedDate) {
        this.notifiedDate = notifiedDate;
    }
    public Long getEndpointId() {
        return this.endpointId;
    }
    public void setEndpointId(Long endpointId) {
        this.endpointId = endpointId;
    }
    public Long getZoneId() {
        return this.zoneId;
    }
    public void setZoneId(Long zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }
    public Zone getZone() {
        return this.zone;
    }
    public void setZone(Zone zone) {
        this.zone = zone;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately that wasn't the issue here.